# Add tabs in dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Does anyone know an easy way to add tabs inside Bootstrap dropdown menus?
Now the problem is, when I open dropdown menu and click on any tab, the dropdown closes. This an expected behavior of any dropdown.

How to avoid closing of a dropdown, if click was inside that dropdown and close it only on outside click or button click.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525440/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-with-tabs-inside

Answer (score 0):

check for the event target on the 'click' function, if the target is within the dropdown then return otherwise process:

function(event) {
     if (typeof event !== "undefined"
    && $("#dropdownid").has(event.target).length > 0) {
    return;
    }
        //do something.
}