# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown with Tabs inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with tabs inside of it. The problem is the dropdown closes when I click a tab. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/pv2Lc/2/. (code reproduced below).

The [cited suggestion to `stopPropagation()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383039/link-dropdown-menu-with-tabs-in-bootstrap) on the tabs anchors doesn't seem to help. Is there a better way?

```
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>           </li>
      <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">HOME asdfasdfsda</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">PROFILE asdfafas</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">MESSAGES asdfdas</div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the specific bootstrap events : the `hide.bs.dropdown` (triggered when the dropdown is about to close) allows you to cancel the "hide" action by calling `e.preventDefault()`. ([doc here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events), list of specific bootstrap events for `scrolldown` components)

You can activate a special flag when the user clicks on a tab, and check that flag in the `hide.bs.dropdown` event on the dropdown  :

```
$('#myTabs').on('click', '.nav-tabs a', function(){
    // set a special class on the '.dropdown' element
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').addClass('dontClose');
})

$('#myDropDown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('dontClose') ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).removeClass('dontClose');
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pv2Lc/4/)
(I added html ids to your example, change the selectors according to your needs)

Answer (score 13):

The cited suggestion doesn't work because the [`.tab('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage) method should be invoked on the actual tab (i.e., the link) instead of the tab pane.

So the code should be:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()        
    $(this).tab('show')
})
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2Lc/6/

Comment: yes this works too! and is slightly cleaner code, though it does change the hash.

Comment: @timpeterson Well, yeah, of course it does... Change the `href`'s to `data-target`'s and it is solved, I just used your original code. It didn't say anywhere that you wanted it differently... In fact, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2Lc/7/

Comment: Works with Bootstrap 4 too.