# DROPDOWN not want to stay open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hello everyone I would like to ask for help because my dropdown is in trouble, as you can see in the link below , it has two tabs , the problem is when you have to change page to see the contents of the one in question , but when you try page to change the dropdown closes. Who can help ?
Link:https://jsfiddle.net/f0yzyryL/`<i>please help</i>`

Comment: Need to share the code in the question, not just a link

Comment: your close event is propogating/bubbling. start there.

Comment: @arun-p-johny I guess he don't know which code is in question. as said already by `jf-it` - you need to stop bubbling when click on tab happens

Comment: I will post a solution in few mins if no one will

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown with Tabs inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525440/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-with-tabs-inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9tywtn6z/

Added js variant from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

instead of http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup

```
$('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show');
  return false;
})
```

and removed `data-toggle="tab"` attr

(or you can use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events to prevent bubbling)

`return false;` preventing bubbling in jquery - https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
$(".nav li").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").addClass("nav-open");
});
```

Add this css:

```
.nav-open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

here is a link: https://jsfiddle.net/vexqhyb9/1/