# tabs inside a dropdown -twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

is that possible?. i'm planning on making one but have no idea how to do it. i'm using bootstrap tho. this is all i have right now

```
<li data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Vehicles</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu nav-tabs" role="menu">

        <hr/>
        <li class=" active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cars">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#vans">Vans & Pick-Up</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mpv">MPVs</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#suv">Crossover & SUVs</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#hybrid">Hybrid</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#performance">Performance</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible.

Comment: can you give me an example? i tried putting values under those tabs that i made it dosen't appear inside but outside of the content of the dropdown  :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown with Tabs inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525440/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-with-tabs-inside)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is something like what you're looking for:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the `href` attribute of the `data-toggle="tab"` needs to correspond to the ID of external content.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hm ok i'll try this one and play with it see what i can do

Comment: im having an issue. i dunno if it's related but i put it inside a <li> and its not changing .

Comment: Update: its working on its own but when i put it inside my <li> it's not hmm